# Gitlab runner upload artifact timeout

Tags: macos, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, kvm, macos-mojave

I have GitLab runner installed on a MacOS using homebrew. The runner configuration is located under `${HOME}/.gitlab-runner/config.toml` and service configuration located under `${HOME}/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.gitlab-runner.plist` is the default.
Below is my `gitlab-runner` toml configuration file.

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "MY_RUNNER_NAME"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "MY_GITLAB_TOKEN"
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "bash"
  environment = ["PATH=/usr/local/opt/openjdk@8/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby@2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin", "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8", "LANG=en_US.UTF-8"]
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
```

The runner is connected correctly to `Gitlab.com`, it executes the steps correctly, but it got stuck in the `Uploading artifacts` step until the build times out.
Below is my `Uploading artifacts` logs.

```
Uploading artifacts...
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=darwin pid=16690 revision=775dd39d version=13.8.0
android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab: found 1 matching files and directories 
ERROR: Job failed: execution took longer than 1h0m0s seconds
```

As a debugging step, I tried to run the `gitlab-runner artifacts-uploader` locally to trace the behavior using this command `gitlab-runner --debug --log-level debug artifacts-uploader --verbose --id MY_BUILD_ID --token MY_GITLAB_TOKEN --url https://gitlab.com/ --path android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab --expire-in "1 week"`.
Below is my `gitlab-runner artifacts-uploader` logs.

```
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=darwin pid=25259 revision=775dd39d version=13.8.0
android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab: found 1 matching files and directories
Dialing: tcp gitlab.com:443 ...
```

It is obvious that the `gitlab-runner artifacts-uploader` got stuck connecting to `gitlab.com:443`, and now I am out of ideas on how to trace or solve this issue.

Comment: did you get solutions after it?

Comment: Nope, I lost hope and changed the approach entirely.